# Return viewBag into Master page MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, controller, master-pages

I want to return `ViewBag` into my Master Page, but I don't have much experience with MVC Razor so I don't know how to solve my problem, here is my code:

Controllers:

`MasterController.cs`

```
public class SharedController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SiteMaster()
    {
        ViewBag.PageTitle = "Show this text into my MasterPage";
        return View();
    }
}
```

and

`HomeController.cs`

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
        return View();
      }
    }
```

Views:

Shared -> `SiteMaster.cshtml`

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <div>@ViewBag.PageTitle</div>  //Doesn't work
 <div>@RenderBody()</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Home   -> `Index.cshtml`

```
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/SiteMaster.cshtml";
 } 
 <div>Test</div>
```

App_Start -> `RouteConfig.cs`

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: You want that `ViewBag.PageTitle` every time you display a view ?

Comment: Yes, because I have master page, I need that `View Bag` to be displayed on every page that includes the `Master Page`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a global ActionFilter :

```
public class MasterPageTitleFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.PageTitle = "Show this text into my MasterPage";
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

If you set this filter to an action, it will trigger when it ends, before generating the view, in order to add your title in the `ViewBag`.

In order to use it for every action/controller without tagging all of them, add this to your global filters registration :

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    // other filters to add
    filters.Add(new MasterPageTitleFilterAttribute());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just have to put your viewbag assignment into your index action of your homecontroller.  Your sitemaster action is not invoked.

Comment: I've just tried that, but it doesn't work, and however, I need that viewbag to be displayed just on the master page layout, and be separated from the other pages

Comment: The samples have code to overwrite viewbag items in the cshtml files sometimes - maybe check that it's not being reset somehow in your razor?

Comment: What happens when you put the viewbag assignment in your index action and try to display it in your index.cshtml - does it make it at least that far?  FYI - I tried what you're describing in a new project and it works fine (that is with the assignment in the INDEX action).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this creating a base controller which inlcudes overrided method

```
public class BaseController: Controller
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.PageTitle = "Show this text into my MasterPage";
            //base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        }
}
```

then you will inherit your other controllers from BaseController. As a result you will reach  ViewBag.PageTitle every time in masterPage..

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
...
}
```

Comment: Error 1 'Belina.Controllers.BaseController.OnActionExecuted(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutedContext)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.OnActionExecuted(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutedContext)'

Comment: ok you are right, i tried, i miss something I edited answer, not OnActionExecuted it must be OnActionExecuting it works.

Answer (score -1):

You need to assign your viewbag in the actions.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
        ViewBag.PageTitle = "Show this text into my MasterPage";
        return View();
      }
}
```